# Calendar widget link to list a day's events

Tags: 7, datetime, entities

I am using the [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module to manage an events calendar on a new site. Currently when you click on a day in the widget it takes the user to the calendar page that shows a small list of the titles.

Is there a way to create a view that shows all of the days, and events for that day, in a single spread and bypasses the calendar completely?

Answer (score 0):

I have got it: If you go to the *Day* view under the Calendar view, you can change the format to *HTML list* and show fields. From there, add the fields of the calendar event you want to show.